# Cropping an image out from the background context

Tags: javascript

I have shape like the following image
[image: this], I need to crop the shape out from the background context in Javascript. The shape data is in the format of base64. I need to somehow read the image in a binary format but I am not how to do this in Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [OpenCV.js](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/df/d0a/tutorial_js_intro.html) to read the data. What you are trying to do is called *Background Substraction*.

There is even a specific tutorial [(OpenCV - Background Substraction)](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/de/df4/tutorial_js_bg_subtraction.html) for what you are trying to accomplish.

In a nutshell, (1) you read the data, (2) you create a mask with what you are trying to delete, and then you use the data and the mask to create a new output.

The mask is nothing more than another image. One where white means *keeping* a pixel, and black means *deleting* it.